# Missing parameter error from google API

Tags: google-bigquery, google-apis-explorer

I am using OutSystems to connect to the Google BigQuery API. 
I am able to query data and when I only send a select query The response is succesfull.

When I try to append the query to a table I use a slightly different request body and I keep getting the following error;

```
 HTTP/1.1 400 BadRequest
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Vary: X-Origin,Origin,Accept-Encoding
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="44,43,39,35"
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Accept-Ranges: none
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Date: Tue, 28 Aug 2018 10:07:22 GMT
Expires: Tue, 28 Aug 2018 10:07:22 GMT
Server: GSE
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "required",
        "message": "Required parameter is missing"
      }
    ],
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Required parameter is missing"
  }
}
```

My request is;

```
 {
"configuration" : {
    "query" : {
        "query" : "SELECT * FROM  Dataset.Table1 WHERE 1 = 1",
        "createDisposition" : "CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
        "destinationTable" : {
            "datasetId" : "DatasetId",
            "projectId" : "projectId",
            "tableId" : "table2Id"
            },
        "useLegacySql" : false,
        "writeDispostion" : "WRITE_APPEND"
        }
    }
}
```

I am using the following URL to send the request; 
https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/{project}/queries

What am I missing? Could not find it in the Google API documentation.

Answer (score 2):

You're using `writeDispostion` instead of `writeDisposition`, additionally, you could check the `[Required]` property names within [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.query).